# Where are the handles on this NURBS curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm working on stylized eyelashes for a character sculpt, and I'd like to make a sharp turn at this point.

[image: The curve that I'm attempting to add a sharp turn to.]

I believe it's a NURBS curve. The path was created with `Shift` + `A` > Curve > Path. I hit `v` and set the handle type to Free, but I don't see any handles.

I've tried setting the spline type to Bezier, but the results weren't pretty and the handles don't appear to do anything.

[image: After setting the spline type to Bezier.]

Where are the handles on my NURBS curve?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, NURBS curves do not have handles (only beziers have handles.)  Instead, the curvature of NURBS curves is adjusted by adjusting each control's "W" component, which I access on sidebar/item/transform.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Click this checkbox while in edit mode for the curve.
[image]